# How can I get lodash orderBy to sort list of items using select element in React?

Tags: reactjs, sorting, lodash

I am trying to use a select element to set internal state to either 'ascending' or 'descending'. Once the state is set, I would like to use that state value to conditionally sort A-Z or Z-A with orderBy from the lodash package. I know the sort method works because I have console logged them, but for some reason my handleSort function is not sorting my array of items at all.

Here is my code:

```
import { useState } from "react";
import { orderBy } from "lodash";

const Subjects = () => {
  const { data } = useQuery(GET_SUBJECTS);
  const [sortState, setSortState] = useState("-");

  let sortedSubjects = data.subjects;

  const handleSort = (e) => {
    setSortState(e.target.value);

    if (sortState === "ascending") {
      sortedSubjects = orderBy(data.subjects, "name", "asc");
    } else if (sortState === "descending") {
      sortedSubjects = orderBy(data.subjects, "name", "desc");
    }
  };

  return (
    <>
      <select
        onChange={handleSort}
        defaultValue="default"
        className="home-page-filter"
      >
        <option value="default">-</option>
        <option value="ascending">A-Z</option>
        <option value="descending">Z-A</option>
      </select>
      <h2>Subject</h2>
      
      <div className="subjects-container">
        {sortedSubjects.map((subject) => (
          <SubjectRow key={subject.id} subject={subject} />
        ))}
      </div>
    </>
  );
};

export default Subjects;
```

I've tried putting the sort function directly in the JSX wondering if it was some sort of hoisting issue. I'm still a junior dev, so it might be something very simple and somewhat obvious that I'm missing or doing wrong here. Thank you for any help!

Answer (score 0):

Remove the if blocks from handleSort, and change your options values to be `asc` and `desc`

```
    const [sortState, setSortState] = useState("default");
    
    const sortedSubjects = orderBy(data.subjects, "name", sortState)
    
    const handleSort = (e) => {
      setSortState(e.target.value);
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

The `sortedSubjects` is computed using `data` and `sortState`. This means that you need to compute it on each render.

Compute `sortedSubjects` each the body of the component. Whenever the component is re-rendered it would be re-computed. If you want to avoid doing it on each render, wrap it with `useMemo`.

In addition, instead use `asc` and `desc` as the options value, which would shorten you code a bit (see comments in code).

Because you have the array (`data`) and the `sortState`

```
const Subjects = () => {
  const { data } = useQuery(GET_SUBJECTS);
  const [sortState, setSortState] = useState("default");
  
  // compute sortedSubject whenever data.subjects or sortState changes
  const sortedSubjects = useMemo(() => 
    sortState === "default" 
    ? data.subjects // return unsort if deafult
    : orderBy(data.subjects, "name", sortState) // sort by sortState
  , [data.subjects, sortState]);

  const handleSort = (e) => {
    setSortState(e.target.value);
  };

  return (
    <>
      <select
        onChange={handleSort}
        defaultValue="default"
        className="home-page-filter"
      >
        <option value="default">-</option>

        {/* change the values to asc/desc */}
        <option value="asc">A-Z</option>
        <option value="desc">Z-A</option>
      </select>
      <h2>Subject</h2>
      
      <div className="subjects-container">
        {sortedSubjects.map((subject) => (
          <SubjectRow key={subject.id} subject={subject} />
        ))}
      </div>
    </>
  );
};
```